# Why does Clojure (1.8) create a HashMap if I manually create a map with > 8 keys, but an ArrayMap if I use zipmap to create map with > 8 keys?

Tags: data-structures, clojure

I know that Clojure switches from `PersistentArrayMap` to `PersistentHashMap` when a map is greater than 8 in size (8 key-value pairs). This can be verified by:

```
(type {0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 8 8})
=> clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap
```

But if I create the above map using `zipmap`:

```
(type (zipmap (range 9) (range 9)))
=> clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap
```

I made sure that the construction is correct:

```
(= (zipmap (range 9) (range 9))
   {0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 8 8})
=> true
```

If I use `(range 10)`, it starts using `PersistentHashMap`. So for `zipmap`, the size has to be 9 or greater before it starts using `PersistentHashMap`.

I found this very weird. Why is there a difference in datastructure depending on whether I create a map manually or with `zipmap`?

I'm using Clojure 1.8.

Answer (score 6):

This is because `zipmap` creates the map incrementally using `assoc`. Because of a bug, `assoc` switches from `ArrayMap` to `HashMap` for size > 9, not for 9.
Look at this:

```
(type {0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7})  
=> clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap       # size = 8

(type (assoc {0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7}
             8 8))
=> clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap       # size = 9

(type (assoc {0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7}
             8 8 9 9))
=> clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap        # size = 10
```

The bug was fixed here: https://github.com/clojure/clojure/commit/ce9fbf61f113fdef1cbf8c1c0b4ea1a48831beef